# Differentiate user centered design and user experience design

Tags: ux-field, ucd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is user experience design (UXD) equal to user centered design (UCD)?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/30093/is-user-experience-design-uxd-equal-to-user-centered-design-ucd)

I am struggling to understand the UX roles with UCD. Can someone explain?